# Set Progress bar Style Value dynamically using Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

40% Complete (success)

---

Can we use Style Width Value dynamically using Asp.Net C# Code ?

Please suggest .
Style="Width: 40% (Dynamically from database ASP.NET C#)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set widht of some element from database on view load? Is it mvc project?

Comment: I would suggest you to use jquery here. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Yes Style width Value using Database MS SQL C# . We can do it using Angular but want to try with C#